# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'male')" when setting object value based on array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does it this not work when doing it with one testObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]]=5 works fine but once I add one more it doesn't work.

```js
const testObject = {
  course: "Math",
  gender: "male",
};
const newObject = {};
newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]][Object.values(testObject)[1]] = 5;
console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: since `newObject.Math` is undefined, you can't set `newObject.Math.male = 5`

Comment: It might be worth explaining to us why you think it _should_ work.  In other words.  What are you expecting to have happen?  "It doesn't work" is **never** a sufficiently detailed description of what happened.

Comment: @Wyck Good point, But I do now understand how I messed up the logic of Objects by trying to create a nested object of a object that doesn't exsist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]]` which translates to `newObject.Math` is `undefined` and with the chained `[]` you first try to read a property `newObject.Math` which is `undefined` and JavaScript will not allow you to do that.
You need to assign e.g an empty object to `newObject.Math` to be able to assign this object other properties.

```js
const testObject = {
  course: "Math",
  gender: "male",
};

const newObject = {};
console.log(newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]]) // undefined
// this tries to read "undefined" which is not possible
//newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]][Object.values(testObject)[1]]
// to make it work assign it an object
newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]] = {};
// now you can assign a new property on that object a value
newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]][Object.values(testObject)[1]] = 5;
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, `newObject` is an empty object and when we do `newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]][Object.values(testObject)[1]]=5` firstly it woyld grab the first part of the expression which is `newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]]` whoes value is `undefined` as the newObject does not have any key as such. Now js engine would try to get the second part of the expression `newObject[Object.values(testObject)[0]][Object.values(testObject)[1]]=5`
And it would be translated to something like this `undefined.[Object.values(testObject)[1]]=5` and as undefined is not the object so it give the error as cant read the property of undefined